# Freezing Gridview Header in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I really thankful to the support given by  the members of this site till now...

It is really Helpful to me...I am looking for the solution of "How to freeze the Header using JavaScript and CSS in Mozilla Firefox?"

I searched all over the internet but i could not find it..please suggest me some ideas,,if you have any links please provide me..

```
<style type="text/css">
       .WrapperDiv 
        {
           width:560px;height:290px;border: 1px solid black;
        }        
       .WrapperDiv TH 
        {
       /* Needed for IE */
        position: relative;
        }
      .WrapperDiv TR 
        {
       /* Needed for IE */
        height:0px;
         }
    .ScrollContent 
    {
    /* Needed for Opera */
    display: block;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px;
     }
     .FixedHeader
     {
    /* Needed for opera */
    display: block;
}
```

What style should i give for mozilla browser??

Comment: Why my visual studio 2010 (HTML 4.01)does not support overflow property?? It is showing"Overflow property is not a known CSS Property"

Comment: Avoid to design with the visual studio, have a limited browser capability, and is 4 years old (the 2010).... Use some new and fast browser, to make this tests.